# Visual studio 2010-C#: Go to a specific row in DataGridView

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

for example:
Go to the next row
or
Going into the last row
or
Going to the Row 4

What code should be written?

Comment: In Silverlight? Be more specific.

Comment: Datagridview in c# for windows application.<br>
DataGrivView1.CurrentRow.Index---->Getting the selected row<br>
To select a row by writing code? (Not with a mouse selection)<br>
for example: first row or row 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set DataGridView1.CurrentCell to first cell of the needed row:

[DataGridView.CurrentRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx)
To change the current row, you must set the CurrentCell property to a cell in the desired row.

[DataGridView.CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx)
The DataGridViewCell that represents the current cell, or null if there is no current cell. The default is the first cell in the first column or null if there are no cells in the control.

Comment: This code just selects the row. But I want to change the current record<br>
So that when I wrote the code DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index<br>
The output record is selected<br>

Or more simply say:<br>
I want the current record (DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index) to change.<br>
Thanks